# Navigate by tapping on the dots of UIPageControl

Tags: ios, uipagecontrol

I've implemented a `UIPageControl` as a outlet in my code. Now I want to have the capability where I can navigate to a specific view controller by tapping a dot in the UIPageControl.

To achieve this I've added an IBAction to the `UIPageControl` and in the implementation I'm taking the `currentPage` to load that specific view controller

```
-(IBAction)pageControlDotDidTap:(id)sender {
    if (![sender isKindOfClass:[UIPageControl class]]) {
        return;
    }
    
    NSInteger selectedPage = [(UIPageControl *)sender currentPage];
    
    // got the currentPage now I can load the view controller

}
```

But the problem is by default UIPageControl moves 1 page at a time. Link: [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol#:~:text=The%20page%20control%20advances%20only%20one%20page%20in%20either%20direction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol#:%7E:text=The%20page%20control%20advances%20only%20one%20page%20in%20either%20direction).

So when I'm on the rightmost dot, If I clicked on the leftmost dot it only navigate to the second rightmost dot.

Is it possible to achieve that, the dot I'm clicking the `UIPageControl` will return that dot number instead of moving one a time?

Comment: No, the `UIPageControl` component only sends "value changed" messages. Quick searching for `swift custom UIPageControl` comes up with many results... you should be able to find one that gives you that functionality -- or at least is close enough that you could easily create your own.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. After some more searching I've got that there is no API available to achieve this by using UIPageControl directly. Thanks to @DonMag for mentioning the should be approach.

Thus I've implemented a Custom Class to have the functionality to load the specific tapped view controller by tapping any indicator in UIPageControl

Here is my implementation -

```
import UIKit

protocol CustomPageControlDelegate: AnyObject {
func customPageControl(_ pageControl: UIPageControl, didTapIndicatorAtIndex index: Int)
}

class CustomPageControl: UIPageControl {

    weak var delegate: CustomPageControlDelegate?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupTapGesture()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupTapGesture()
    }

    private func setupTapGesture() {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

    @objc private func handleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let tapPoint = gesture.location(in: self)
        if let tappedIndicatorIndex = indicatorIndex(for: tapPoint) {
            currentPage = tappedIndicatorIndex
            delegate?.customPageControl(self, didTapIndicatorAtIndex: tappedIndicatorIndex)
    }
}

    private func indicatorIndex(for tapPoint: CGPoint) -> Int? {
        let indicatorSize: CGFloat = 7.0 // Adjust this value according to your indicator size
        let spacing: CGFloat = 10.0 // Adjust this value according to your spacing between indicators
    
        let totalWidth = CGFloat(numberOfPages) * indicatorSize + CGFloat(numberOfPages - 1) * spacing
        let startX = (bounds.size.width - totalWidth) / 2.0
    
        if tapPoint.x >= startX && tapPoint.x < startX + totalWidth {
            let relativeX = tapPoint.x - startX
            let indicatorIndex = Int(relativeX / (indicatorSize + spacing))
            return indicatorIndex
        }
    
        return nil
    }
}
```

After that in the view controller I've used the delegate function to load the tapped indicator's view controller -

```
  func customPageControl(_ pageControl: UIPageControl, didTapIndicatorAtIndex index: Int) {
    print("Tapped indicator at index: \(index)")
    // Handle the tap event and update your view accordingly
    // Example: Scroll to the corresponding page in a UIScrollView
}
```